# Split array into two arrays by value even or odd 5

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to split the following array into odd and even array by e.g `[SUBJECT_CODE] => 05`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => English
            [subject_name] => English
            [1] => E-I
            [subject_abr] => E-I
            [2] => 
            [ENROL_NO] => 
            [3] => 2013
            [YEAR_] => 2013
            [4] => 1
            [EXAM_CODE] => 1
            [5] => 42701
            [ROLL_NO] => 42701
            [6] => 01
            [SUBJECT_CODE] => 01          
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => English
            [subject_name] => English
            [1] => E-II
            [subject_abr] => E-II
            [2] => 027-B/FMSGUK-2011
            [ENROL_NO] => 027-B/FMSGUK-2011
            [3] => 2013
            [YEAR_] => 2013
            [4] => 1
            [EXAM_CODE] => 1
            [5] => 42701
            [ROLL_NO] => 42701
            [6] => 02
            [SUBJECT_CODE] => 02         

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Urdu
            [subject_name] => Urdu
            [1] => U-I
            [subject_abr] => U-I
            [2] => 
            [ENROL_NO] => 
            [3] => 2013
            [YEAR_] => 2013
            [4] => 1
            [EXAM_CODE] => 1
            [5] => 42701
            [ROLL_NO] => 42701
            [6] => 05
            [SUBJECT_CODE] => 05

        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, a simple foreach should suffice. Consider this example:

```
// $values is your original array
$new_values = array();
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    if($value['SUBJECT_CODE'] & 1) {
        $new_values['odd'][] = $value;
    } else {
        $new_values['even'][] = $value;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_values);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: sir bundle of  thanks for ur response ...where will be the new values store odd and even ... i am new to php please help

Comment: @user3717373 all values which has odd subject codes should be inside `$new_values['odd']` while even ones should be inside `$new_values['even']` in this example.

Comment: or just `$new_values[$value['CODE'] % 2][]=$value`.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Traverse through the array

```
$odd = array();
$even = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if ($key % 2 == 0) {
        $even[] = $value;
    }
    else {
        $odd[] = $value;
    }
}
}
```

The odd value are stored in the $odd array and even in the $even.
You can print_r($odd)